# How to get collection request name at newman cli postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I want to save my all response file with their request name. So I am finding a solution where I get the request name. Newman CLI is a command-line tool to run the postman collection but I read out all documentation and not get any solution for the same.

```
const newman = require('newman'),
fs = require('fs');
var envPath = "./env/POP.postman_environment.json";
var res;
newman.run({
    collection: require('./collection/login_HHS.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli',
    environment:require(`${envPath}`),
    exportEnvironment: `${envPath}`
}).on('beforeRequest', function (error, args) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
          fs.writeFile('request.txt', args.request.body.raw, function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });    
    }
}).on('request', function (error,args) {
     if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log("args ====== "+args.response.stream)
        res = args.response.stream;

    }
}).on('test', function (error, summary) {
     if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        const fileName = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + '-foo.txt';

        fs.writeFile(fileName, res, function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });  

    }      

});
```

Comment: If you wanted a report of the run including all that info without trying to split it up like that - you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra

Comment: have you used console.log(pm.info.requestName); ?